# Ideas for logging a Java Windows Service without additional libraries when the application dies

Tags: java, windows, windows-services, error-logging

I can't imagine I'll have much luck but I'll ask anyway.

I have an application that I have ported to a Windows Service using Apache Daemon.  It starts off by reading in a couple of initialization files but terminates if anything goes wrong.  Due to restrictions, I am unable to bring in new software so logging to the Windows Logger through third party libraries like the Java JNA aren't an option.  (The Windows Logger would have been nice.)

Does anyone have any ideas, aside from writing to our text logger, how a Windows Service would generally report an abnormal termination.

Linux developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Services will record errors, warnings and other bits of information to the [Windows Event Logs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer), usually in the "Windows Logs > Application" section. Check there to see if Apache Daemon has left you any helpful details.